# extract ruleset form @rest and execute it

Tags: less

I want to dynamically get to a specific ruleset passed in as an argument to a function and execute it.

However, am ensure how to execute the `@ruleset` as extracted from `@rest`

This is the example (contrived):

```
 .switch{
        @names: ~"a-switch-with-tick-success", ~"a-switch-with-tick";

        @a: { 
            .switch-with-tick(@brand-success)
        };

        @b: { 
            .switch-with-tick();
        };

        .loop(1, @a, @b);
    }


    .loop(@counter, @rest...) when (@counter <=length(@names)) {
       @var: extract(@names, @counter);
       &.@{var}, .@{var} &{
            @ruleset: extract(@rest, @counter);
            //somehow execute ruleset
       }
      .loop(@counter + 1, @rest);
    }
```

**EDIT**

Somehow the obvious thing below now seems to work.

```
    .switch{
        @names: ~"a-switch-with-tick-success", ~"a-switch-with-tick";

        @a: { 
            .switch-with-tick(@brand-success)
        };

        @b: { 
            .switch-with-tick();
        };

        .loop(1, @a, @b);
    }


    .loop(@counter, @rest...) when (@counter <=length(@names)) {
       @var: extract(@names, @counter);
       &.@{var}, .@{var} &{
            @ruleset: extract(@rest, @counter);
            @ruleset();
       }
      .loop(@counter + 1, @rest);
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I was just about to say the same thing :) Good that you have found it yourself. Maybe you should post it as an answer to help others in future (or) remove the question because I don't think it is right to have the solution in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the obvious thing below now seems to work.

```
.switch{
    @names: ~"a-switch-with-tick-success", ~"a-switch-with-tick";

    @a: { 
        .switch-with-tick(@brand-success)
    };

    @b: { 
        .switch-with-tick();
    };

    .loop(1, @a, @b);
}


.loop(@counter, @rest...) when (@counter <=length(@names)) {
   @var: extract(@names, @counter);
   &.@{var}, .@{var} &{
        @ruleset: extract(@rest, @counter);
        @ruleset();
   }
  .loop(@counter + 1, @rest);
}
```